# How to combine cts:search searchable-expression and cts:not-query?

Tags: marklogic

I have been using `cts:search` with **searchable-expression** to extract specific elements from XML documents. For example:

Document:

```
<book>
  <recipe>
    <ingredients>cinnamon, peppermint</ingredients>
    <instruction/>
  </recipe>
  <recipe>
    <ingredients>sugar, peppermint</ingredients>
    <instruction/>
  </recipe>
  <recipe>
    <ingredients>coconut oil</ingredients>
    <instruction/>
  </recipe>
</book>
```

Query:

```
cts:search(//recipe, cts:parse("peppermint"))
```

Results:

```
<recipe>
  <ingredients>cinnamon, peppermint</ingredients>
  <instruction>
  </instruction>
</recipe>
<recipe>
  <ingredients>sugar, peppermint</ingredients>
  <instruction>
  </instruction>
</recipe>
```

However, this doesn't work with `cts:not-query` and no result is returned for the following search:

```
cts:search(//recipe, cts:parse("-cinnamon"))
```

Looking into the query plan, my understanding is that the `cts:not-query` is applied at the fragment (document) level prior to filtering so the above document is eliminated outright. If that is correct, this behavior makes sense.

Nevertheless I am still wondering if this can be accomplished somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Searchable expressions that don't match root nodes are discouraged.

One problem with more complex searchable expressions is that a small change can make the search require filtering.

That's one reason why the SJS version of search - [`cts.search()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.search) - doesn't support searchable expressions.

The recommended approach is

- To model the documents with a separate document for each object / row (recipe in this case) -- which eliminates the potential for false positives in unfiltered search that match parts of the criteria in two different objects.
- To use the `cts:query` argument for matching and to use XPaths on the returned documents for extracting nodes.
- To assemble objects into lists as needed based on queries.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I guess what's special for cts:not-query is that false-positive becomes false-negative. Hence even filtered search won't work. Do you think if it is the case?

Comment: @FanLi -- yes, the not-query prevents the document from getting past the index resolution stage, so filtering won't help.